# Adaptors that work in the various electricity outlets in Europe

Tags: gear, electronic-items, power

Are there any single-plug (not "powerstrip"-style) adapters that can work for Italy, France, the UK, and Switzerland? It seems very cumbersome to have to pack 4 types of adapters.

[image: EU-outlet]
'European' outlet, used in continental EU-countries

[image: British-outlet]
Outlet used in island countries of EU (Britain, Malta, Cyprus, Ireland)

[image: Swiss-outlet]
Swiss outlet

(Image sources - http://tripolo.pl/turystyka/porady/standardy-napiec-i-wtyczek-elektrycznych-na-swiecie/)

**Update:** Both the answers provide what I was looking for, but given the cost and the lack of product reviews on those type of items, I decided against it. I was looking for an adapter from US to Country XYZ that would work for all countries in Europe.

Comment: I actually don't think this is a dupe. The other question is "people have all kinds of plugs on their stuff" and this one is "my stuff goes to countries with all kinds of outlets in the wall"

Comment: MarkE, can you please clarify what kind of adapter you seek? A single universal adaptor, or one adaptor you can plug multiple devices into at once via multiple outlets it provides?

Comment: Seems like everybody *except* @MarkE has had a go at clarifying this question (-:

Comment: Mark, you don't want to skimp on converter plugs. Cheap ones are fire hazards, and can get you electrocuted as well. They may also be illegal in some countries.

Comment: Don't assume that your three illustrations there are all incompatible. The European plug will go into the Swiss outlet, ignoring  the hole for the third pin. My chargers are Norwegian and I spent all summer in Switzerland without being unable to plug in (or getting electrocuted)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In most airports or trains stations, you can buy a multi-adaptor.  They let you switch between almost any country, except South Africa, usually, as it's a ginormous plug.

Example:

[image]

Alternatively, look at the link that Andra commented on with, where you could look into a powerstrip with different source plugs that you could adapt to.  However, I figure since you're after different destination plugs, this is something you should consider.

Comment: I think you also missed the `Multiple outlet` bit of `Multiple outlet adapters for Europe` ...

Comment: just bring a normal-for-your-possesions power bar (I have many that would fit in a shirt pocket) and plug the power bar into the adapter

Comment: @hippietrail I took that to mean different outlets for different countries - ie multiple countries, no? The OP says how 4 is a pain, and is visiting 4 countries....

Comment: Hmm yes I suppose I can see how it can be read two ways. I thought he wanted to convert one outlet into multiple outlets. I've asked for clarification.

Comment: Man that's a ginormous plug!

Comment: These are really useful. If you are considering buying one, I suggest one of the variants that also includes USB sockets - very useful for charging gadgets. Here's one example: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Skross-Charger-Designed-Blackberrys-Countries/dp/B003NW1ZME/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1378734304&sr=8-1&keywords=multi+travel+adaptor.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to spend $50 for a "ballistic" one. Here's one I bought for $5 in a 7-11 in Singapore or Thailand when I realized the dedicated adaptor I bought in Malaysia wasn't going to be enough:

[image: $5 universal power adapter]

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried the Tumi adapter kit...? http://www.tumi.com/product/index.jsp?productId=4209721

$ 50 may seem expensive, but it's never let me down. You can also look for cheaper alternatives if you search for "Universal Adapter Kits".

Comment: OP is asking specifically for a multi-outlet adaptor. The one at this link just seems to be a single outlet adaptor.

Comment: I bought something like this Tumi thing in Malaysia or Singapore a few weeks ago for $5 and it's working pretty nicely so far.

Comment: @hippietrail: But the Tumi adapter comes in a "ballistic case", so the 50$ premium charge is probably justified :)

Comment: Is that a case made of of the same ballistics gel that MythBusters use to simulate human flesh? `\-:` Or am I the only one who doesn't know?

Answer (score 4):

I've got the Samsonite Luggage Universal Power Adapter. It works pretty much everywhere, and I really love that it also has two USB ports for charging my devices.

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B004B9RYDM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004B9RYDM)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

[This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country#Table_of_mains_voltages_and_frequencies) provides information about electric plug types used in various countries.

You can find various types of adapters/switchers for this purpose. My girlfriend went to the Balkans and got the following adapter for 15 TL (about $7). She doesn't need to use it much but I guess she used it once or twice and had no problem. The product supports any type of plug and converts it to any other plug type.

PS: I guess [this site has some more details](http://www.eforcity.com/universal-world-wide-travel-charger-adapter-plug-white-cothplugun01.html) about the type of product I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

One not so straight-forward, but cheap alternative would be the following. Note that this will only work for devices with a two-pin plug:

1. Use a US to Europe adapter. with two plugs (this will work with the Swiss plugs as well), there are really cheap ones: [http://www.amazon.com/Ceptics-Europe-Asia-Plug-Adapter/dp/B0084OPT8C/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1378801703&sr=8-1&keywords=us+to+european+plug+adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0084OPT8C)
2. Use a second Europe to UK adapter. For the two-pin version you can get really cheap and simple plastic adapters for less than a dollar. It's not a real adapter, but more of a plastic helping you to fit the EU plug into the UK plug. I didn't find a picture, but I used them all the time in Singapore and they work perfectly and weigh close to nothing. You can achieve the same thing, by using a pen on the third pin to be able to fit the EU plug into the UK socket. (Be cautious though).

Comment: Careful - this sounds a little dangerous. One adapter plugged into another, where one is just helping you fit a plug in that was never supposed to fit? This sounds like a recipe for electrocution! :)

Comment: @AndrewFerrier yet that's exactly how many multiplugs work. I've one that has when fully assembled 6 or 7 plugs all stuck one on top of the other. The fit is snug enough they won't jiggle loose. Of course if you have a poor fit, not recommended.

Comment: as to that EU to UK plug mentioned however, that one you'd best not use as it sounds like something that'd be illegal in the UK (where by law those things must be grounded, certainly if the device you stick in has grounding prongs).

Comment: Yes, this only works for two-pin devices. For the UK plugs, those plugs have the third pin (ground) made of plastic, which is not grounded at all.